# Kubernetes rolling update / Create new containers one by one

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

We're having 3 replicas of a given deployment.

For now during a new deployment, we're having concurrently the following :

```
default   app-new-tag   0/2     ContainerCreating
default   app-new-tag   0/2     ContainerCreating
default   app-new-tag   0/2     ContainerCreating
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
```

What we would like to achieve, would be to only to only **have a single container in a `ContainerCreating` state** at a time.

For example :

```
default   app-new-tag   0/2     Pending
default   app-new-tag   0/2     Pending
default   app-new-tag   0/2     ContainerCreating
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
```

Then :

```
default   app-new-tag   0/2     Pending
default   app-new-tag   0/2     ContainerCreating
default   app-new-tag   0/2     Running
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
default   app-old-tag   2/2     Running
```

etc...

Is that something achievable with the existing options ?

Comment: Is there any issue with what is happening currently ? Or You are trying to achieve something with this change ?

Comment: As describe (sorry for our english), we want to achieve the following : `What we would like to achieve, would be to only to only have a single container in a ContainerCreating state at a time.`

Comment: Yes that I understood, but is there any reason for that ?

Comment: We're using a rails app. A rails app, when it starts, run a migration task. This task can't happen concurrently. So basically, if two containers are running this script at the same time, it fails. I know others approaches to get through this sort of issue. Knowing that, I'm not trying here to solve anything about this migrations 'issue'. Rather interested to know if pods can be rolled out as described within the kubernetes capabilities. And that's the only reason that made me post here

Comment: Okay as per my knowledge, Rolling update will start creating all replicas at a time and as and when each of them start running older ones are deleted to keep the replicas constant. So I don't think it would be possible to start new containers one by one.

Comment: @Ben : Is your issue resolved? If yes, can you provide the resolution steps you have followed and provide it as an answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Comment: @HemanthKumar not really as i could not spend more time into it; just dealing with it (as it is not ultimately blocking for me)